# Rails 4 - Paperclip - Upload an image using DATA URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip, uri, data-uri

Here my question, I'm using Rails 4 and paperclip to handle image uploading to my amazon s3 server.
However, I want to allow user to use their own webcam to take a picture instead of selecting an existing file on their hard drive.

When I'm capturing the image, I get as a result an **image data URI** similar to that :

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

My question is : how do I upload that image based on that data URI using paperclip in my image controller ?

Is there a way that I can pass that DATA URI directly to my controller and paperclip will take care of it?
Or do I have to create and write a temp file to reconstruct the image and then pass it to paperclip?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Paperclip#io_adapters.for` will try to find the right adapter for the job, in this case [`Paperclip::DataUriAdapter`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/io_adapters/data_uri_adapter.rb) . You could also use `Paperclip::DataUriAdapter` directly of course.

```
def save_data_uri_to_attachment(data_uri)    

  # Instantiates Paperclip::DataUriAdapter attachment
  file = Paperclip.io_adapters.for(data_uri)
  file.original_filename = name

  # Save the model  
  model.attachment = file
  model.save!
end
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28036282/545017