# How to upload a Base 64 image to Rails paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, paperclip

I've tried a million different tutorials on the internet for how to upload a Base64 image from my iOS application to my rails app. It seems that no matter how I format the request it just won't get accepted.

Does anyone know definitively how to upload a Base64 image to paperclip?

I tried sending the param as JSON

```
{ "thumbnail_image": "base64_data..." }
```

I also tried appending the data url

```
{ "thumbnail_image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,alkwdjlaks..." }
```

I tried sending a JSON object with and without data url

```
{ "thumbnail_image": { "filename": "thumbnail.jpg", "file_data": "base64_data...", "content_type": "image/jpeg" } }
```

I consistently get these `Paperclip::NoHandlerError`s and then it dumps a giant blob of data into my log.

Answer (score 11):

Your Base64 string seems to be fine. You can always check that **[here](http://www.base64-image.net/)**

So the problem is probably on the Rails side. Check that the string you receive is exactly the same like the one you are sending.

With Paperclip **4.2.1** I managed to save Base64 GIF file that way:

Having:

```
class Thing
    has_attached_file :image
```

and POST attributes:

```
{
    "thumbnail_data:" "data:image/gif;base64,iVBORw0KGgo..."
}
```

All you have to do is to find proper adapter and specify original_filename. So for controller that would be:

```
def create
    image = Paperclip.io_adapters.for(params[:thumbnail_data]) 
    image.original_filename = "something.gif"
    Thing.create!(image: image)
    ...
end
```

AFAIK Paperclip made it easier to save base64 from version 3.5.0.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Indeed, this works in Paperclip 3.5.4, at least. It does not work in v. 3.4.2, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have done it in the past and it is basically a brute force approach, not sure if paperclip has added better support in recent versions, but this should work

```
class FooBar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :thumbnail_image
  validates_attachment_content_type :thumbnail_image,
                                     content_type: %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png image/gif),
                                     message: "is not gif, png, jpg, or jpeg." 

  attr_accessor :base64_thumbnail_image

  # call this explicitly from the controller or in an after_save callback
  # after setting the base64_thumbnail_image attribute
  def save_base64_thumbnail_image
    if base64_thumbnail_image.present?
      file_path = "tmp/foo_bar_thumbnail_image_#{self.id}.png"
      File.open(file_path, 'wb') { |f| f.write(Base64.decode64(base64_thumbnail_image)) }
      # set the paperclip attribute and let it do its thing
      self.thumbnail_image = File.new(file_path, 'r')
    end
  end  
end

# params should be base64_thumbnail_image, not thumbnail_image in this case
```

Comment: This looks promising. It sucks that Paperclip basically ignores what has become one of the most common formats of image submission :(

Comment: Unfortunately I got this error. It didn't actually raise an exception, but an image was not saved `Content Type Spoof: Filename thumbnail18.png (["image/png"]), content type discovered from file command: text/plain. See documentation to allow this combination.`

Comment: @BrianWheeler - that is a separate issue - you need to add `validates_attachment_content_type` on the model for any image types that you allow - i'll add to code example above

Comment: I think it goes deeper than that, because I had a proper regex for the file attachment validator