# How to upload image from iOS using Swift to a Ruby/Rails server

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, swift

I have a ruby/rails application that I want to accept an image upload in Base64 format inside of a JSON request payload. The basic app structure is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class NewCafeDetailsTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var submitButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var mainImageCell: AddImageCell!
    var submitData: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        submitData = ["name": "Brian"]
        submitButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("submit"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    }

    func submit() {
        // I\'ve tried to submit a dynamic image, but I switched it to a 
        // hard-coded 1x1 GIF just to get a grip on how to do this on 
        // the backend before attempting too much more
        submitData["thumbnail_data"] = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"
        var error: NSError?

        var submitJSON: NSData!
        submitJSON = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(submitData, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: &error)
        if (error == nil) {
            let submitJSONString = NSString(data: cafeJSON, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            var url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:3000/people.json")
            var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
            var requestData = submitJSONString?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            request.HTTPBody = requestData
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
            request.timeoutInterval = 10

        }
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse) {
        var response = response as NSHTTPURLResponse

            if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode <= 299) {
                self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
                var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Success", message: "Cafe was successfully submitted. We'll review it in a few business days.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
                alert.show()
            } else {
                var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Oops..", message: "It seems there was some kind of server error, please try again later", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
                alert.show()
            }


    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
            var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Oops..", message: "It seems there was some kind of server error, please try again later", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
            alert.show()

        })
    }

}
```

In my Ruby code I have tried a variety of different paperclip options, which seems near broken. I also tried to decode the Base64 and save it myself with little to no success.

Some of the things I tried:

```
data = Base64.decode64(params[:thumbnail_data])
File.open("test.jpg", "wb") do |f| f.write data end

data = Base64.decode64(params[:thumbnail_data].split(",")[-1])
File.open("test.jpg", "wb") do |f| f.write data end
```

It seems like no matter what I do, whenever I try to open the uploaded image preview says that the file has been corrupted. Could the problem be something to do with NSData endianness? or perhaps I'm not formatting the Base64 correctly? I've tried using a variety of gems as well.

Comment: Please check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27234065/how-to-upload-a-base-64-image-to-rails-paperclip/28036282#28036282

Answer (score 0):

You could set your thumbnail_data to just Base64 code as shown below and change the request HTTP body:

```
var submitData: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>!
submitData = ["name": "Brian"]
submitData["thumbnail_data"] = "R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:3000/people")!)
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(submitData, options: [])
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) in
    //Handle server response
}
task.resume()
```

Specially if you want to upload an image directly from the device, in that case you should first create a representation and then encode it:

```
let jpegRep = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.75)
let base64Image = jpegRep!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
```

**Where image is a UIImage object and 0.75 is image quality**

On the server side, if you're using paperclip gem, you should have something like this:

```
image = StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(params[:thumbnail_data]))
Something.create(:image => image)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and after few days of headaches came to solution:

just replace `self.capturePhotoView.image` with your image

```
if let capturePhotoImage = self.capturePhotoView.image {
    if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(capturePhotoImage) {
        let encodedImageData = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    }
}
```

and then decode it like this on your server side assuming you have paperclip on you Image model.

```
image = StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(params[:image].tr(' ', '+')))
image.class.class_eval { attr_accessor :original_filename, :content_type }
image.original_filename = SecureRandom.hex + '.png'
image.content_type = 'image/png'

create_image = Image.new(image: image)
create_image.save!
```

Hope this helps https://blog.kodius.io/2016/12/30/upload-image-from-swift-3-ios-app-to-rails-5-server/