# Upload base64 Image with Paperclip - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, base64, paperclip

I am relatively new to Rails and would appreciate any help.

My website accepts a signature image in base64 format and I am trying to use a Paperclip adaptor to decode the image and save it to my `form` model as the `:signature` attribute. I am using the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28036282/4822174) (and [here](https://gist.github.com/WizardOfOgz/1012107)) which advises to use the following code:

In model:

```
class Thing
    has_attached_file :image
```

In controller:

```
def create
  image = Paperclip.io_adapters.for(params[:thumbnail_data]) 
  image.original_filename = "something.gif"
  Thing.create!(image: image)
  ...
end
```

My assumption is that `Thing.create!` is setting the value of Paperclip's model attribute `:image` to be the value of the `image` variable whilst creating and saving a new Thing object. I tried to implement the same code in my `FormsController` (create action) before `@form.save`, but am receiving this error:

```
undefined method `before_image_post_process' for #<Class:0x007f94a2a26de8>
```

My `FormsController`:

```
class FormsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user
  before_action :admin_user, only: :destroy

  def index
    @forms = Form.all #paginate
  end

  def show
    @form = Form.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @form = Form.new
  end

  def create
    @form = Form.new(form_params)

    # Paperclip adaptor 
    signature = Paperclip.io_adapters.for(params[:base64])
    signature.original_filename = "something.png"

    # Attempt to submit image through Paperclip
    @form.signature = signature

    if @form.save
      flash[:success] = "The form has been successfully created!"
      redirect_to @form
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @form = Form.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @form = Form.find(params[:id])
    if @form.update_attributes(form_params)
      flash[:success] = "Form has been updated!"
      redirect_to @form
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    Form.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Form deleted"
    redirect_to forms_path
  end

  private

  def form_params
    params.require(:form).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, :address, :member_type, :base64)
  end
end
```

This is my `Form` model:

```
class Form < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :signature
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type =>     ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]

 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using the Rails form helpers over in your view, and based on your `form_params` list, the `:base64` key won't be at the top level of your `params` hash, but rather one level down at `params[:form][:base64]`

Comment: Thanks so much! I am glad I wasn't totally off.

Comment: Right now I am using `$("#base64").val(base64);` to assign a value to the `:base64` form attribute. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Well, if you're using the standard Rails form helpers, then the id of that element won't be `base64` it'll be `form_base64` so I'm not sure how that's working, but if you have that working somehow then there's nothing wrong with that at all - efficiency-wise.

Comment: I explicitly gave it an id: `<%= f.hidden_field :base64, id: "base64" %>`, without realizing that the form helper automatically sets the id. Thanks for the tip.